# Strange error printing getline() strings in cout

Tags: c++, string, standards, std, cout

I was trying to test my classes when I encountered a weird problem in the input of test cases.
I tried to simplify the input to see what went wrong so I created the program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string number;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, number))
    {
        std::cout << std::string(number) << " ";
    }
}
```

Basically, I am getting each line of text and storing it in a string variable using **getline()**. Then I display each string using std::cout and append a single space character.

My input file contains this:

```
one six
one seven
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
one six one seven
```

But instead, I get this:

```
 one seven
```

That is a space character followed by the second line of the input. It disregards the first line of input. I know for a fact that each line are being read properly because they were correctly displayed when I replaced the code with this:

```
std::cout << std::string(number) << std::endl;
```

This error is quite new to me. What's happening here? Can anybody explain? TIA!

Comment: try: std::cout << std::string(number) << " "<<std::flush;

Comment: This is very strange. All `std::endl` does differently is flushing the output. Did you try adding `cout.flush()` to the loop?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with g++ or msvc2013. I do know that you don't need to say `std::string(number)` in those `cout` calls. You're creating a temporary copy for no reason. Just do `std::cout << number << ...`

Comment: Please note that the input comes from a text file and I run the program in the command line with this: ./main < input.text

Comment: @dari I tried it but same results.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried that too but still the same.

Comment: @galibee: Are you on Windows and does the text file have Unix (\n) or Windows (\r\n) end-of-lines?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes I'm on windows. I'm using g++ on cygwin. I'm using sublime text and I just pressed enter upon typing every line. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @galibee: Possibly. Can you edit the test file and then be sure it's saved with Windows end-of-lines? Not sure how you select that with sublime text (maybe EOL conversion).

Comment: @Blastfurnace I think the problem is not with the text file formatting since the strings were properly displayed if I replaced the space character with std::endl or "\t".

Comment: @galibee: Run your program and direct the output to another text file. Open that file in your editor and see what it contains. The output you report sounds like a very typical Linux/Windows EOL issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, its clear.

Your input file must be : `one six\r\ntwo seven\r\n` with normal Windows EOL.

When you read it under cygwin, you get in first read `one six\r`, only the `\n` being eaten by `getline`, and same `one seven\r` on the second line.

So you write : `one six\r one seven\r` (with an ending blank). But the `\r` alone put the curson back in first column of same line and second line erases first.

And normally the problem is not visible if you replace the ending blank by a `std::eol` that puts the cursor on a new line. The tab (`\t`) if really a special case : it put the cursor on eighth column exactly where you expect it, but by pure chance. If you invert the two lines it would be more apparent because you would see the remaining of first line at end of second.

You can confirm it by writing the output to a file and editing it.

I could reproduce it under Linux with a Windows EOL. The reason for that is that Cygwin closely mimics Unix-Linux and use Unix EOL convention of only `\n`.